# When installing through pip, how do I tell matplotlib how to find tkinter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-3.3

I have a fresh Python 3.3 installation on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5, including Tkinter — `python3.3 -m tkinter` works and shows a dialogue.  However, when I run `pip3.3 install matplotlib`, at the *Optional Backend Dependencies*, it says:

```
Tkinter: no
         * TKAgg requires Tkinter
```

How does `matplotlib` determine the availability of `Tkinter`, and how can I give it a hint?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you get matplotlib from your distro's repositories. Pip is fine for installing simple, pure Python packages but isn't very convenient for packages such as matplotlib or numpy, for which a lot of non-Python dependencies need to be solved. Your package manager should nicely take care of all this stuff for you.

Comment: I have no root access on this machine, so unless I install in a virtualenv, I'm stuck with python2.6.  I would like to use a newer python version.